# tensorflow element-wise matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication, tensorflow

Say I have two tensors in tensorflow, with the first dimension representing the index of a training example in a batch, and the others representing some vectors of matrices of data.  Eg

```
vector_batch = tf.ones([64, 50])
matrix_batch = tf.ones([64, 50, 50])
```

I'm curious what the most idiomatic way to perform a vector*matrix multiply, for each of the pairs of vectors, matrices that share an index along the first dimension.

Aka a the most idiomatic way to write:

```
result = tf.empty([64,50])
for i in range(64):
    result[i,:] = tf.matmul(vector_batch[i,:], matrix_batch[i,:,:])
```

What would be the best way to organize the shape of the input vectors to make this process as simple/clean as possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the most idiomatic way to do this is using [`tf.batch_matmul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul) operator (in conjunction with [`tf.expand_dims()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#expand_dims) and [`tf.squeeze()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#squeeze):

```
vector_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[64, 50])
matrix_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[64, 50, 50])

vector_batch_as_matrices = tf.expand_dims(vector_batch, 1)
# vector_batch_as_matrices.get_shape() ==> [64, 1, 50]

result = tf.batch_matmul(vector_batch_as_matrices, matrix_batch)
# result.get_shape() ==> [64, 1, 50]

result = tf.squeeze(result, [1])
# result.get_shape() ==> [64, 50]
```

Comment: Hmm  `tf.batch_matmul` does not exist in tf 1 - what would be the equivalent code ? plain matmul ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that tf.matmul already supports this type of "nd" operation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43819275/2930156