# Why does tf.matmul(a,b, transpose_b=True) work, but not tf.matmul(a, tf.transpose(b))?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

Code:

```
x = tf.constant([1.,2.,3.], shape = (3,2,4))
y = tf.constant([1.,2.,3.], shape = (3,21,4))
tf.matmul(x,y)                     # Doesn't work. 
tf.matmul(x,y,transpose_b = True)  # This works. Shape is (3,2,21)
tf.matmul(x,tf.transpose(y))       # Doesn't work.
```

I want to know what shape `y` becomes inside `tf.matmul(x,y,transpose_b = True)` so I can work out what is really going on inside an LSTM with attention.

Answer (score 7):

Transpose can be defined differently for tensors of rank > 2, and here the difference is in axes that are transposed by `tf.transpose` and `tf.matmul(..., transpose_b=True)`.

By default, [`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) does this:

> The returned tensor's dimension `i` will correspond to the input dimension `perm[i]`. If perm is not given, it is set to `(n-1...0)`, where n is the rank of the input tensor. Hence by default, this operation performs a regular matrix transpose on 2-D input Tensors.

So in your case, it's going to transform `y` into a tensor of shape `(4, 21, 3)`, which *is not compatible* with `x` (see below).

But if you set `perm=[0, 2, 1]`, the result *is compatible*:

```
# Works! (3, 2, 4) * (3, 4, 21) -> (3, 2, 21).
tf.matmul(x, tf.transpose(y, [0, 2, 1]))
```

---

### About `tf.matmul`

You can compute the dot product: `(a, b, c) * (a, c, d) -> (a, b, d)`. But it's not tensor dot product -- it's a *batch operation* (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34183343/712995)).

In this case, `a` is considered a batch size, so `tf.matmul` computes `a` dot-products of matrices `(b, c) * (c, d)`.

Batch can be more than one dimension, so this is also valid:

```
(a, b, c, d) * (a, b, d, e) -> (a, b, c, e)
```