# Multiplying Large Number of Matrices and Vectors on Tensorflow TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, distributed, tpu

I am trying to multiply 3000 independent matrices and vectors on TPU in order to speed up calculations, but I have run into some issues.
I am unable to get the final result and I am also interested if there is a better solution.

Here is the code:

```
import time

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


n_dim = 100
num_matrices = 3000
a = np.random.random((num_matrices, n_dim, n_dim)).astype(np.float32)
b = np.random.random((num_matrices, n_dim)).astype(np.float32)

atf = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.float32)
btf = tf.constant(b, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Here is the version on CPU:

```
result = []
tic = time.time()
for i in range(num_matrices):
  result.append(tf.linalg.matvec(atf[i, :, :], btf[i, :]))
toc = time.time()
print(f"Time simple tf elapsed {toc -tic}")
```

Time simple tf elapsed 0.92

Here is the version that I have tried on TPU (Google Colab)

```
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='')
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
# print("All devices: ", tf.config.list_logical_devices('TPU'))
strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)

@tf.function
def matmul_fn(x, y):
  def cond_loop(i, x, y, result):
    return tf.less(i, 3000)

  def body_loop(i, x, y, result):
    result = tf.linalg.matvec(x[i, :, :], y[i, :])
    return [tf.add(i, 1), x, y, result]

  i = tf.constant(0) 
  result = tf.constant(np.zeros(y[0,:].shape), dtype=tf.float32)

  final_result = tf.while_loop(cond_loop, body_loop, [i, x, y, result])
  return final_result

tic = time.time()
z = strategy.run(matmul_fn, args=(atf, btf))
toc = time.time()
print(f"First Time = {toc -tic}")

inference_time = 0.0
num_iterations = 100

for i in range(num_iterations): 
  tic = time.time()
  result = strategy.run(matmul_fn, args=(atf, btf))
  toc = time.time()
  inference_time += toc - tic
  
print(inference_time / num_iterations)
```

Here inference time is only 0.001 but I have the following problems:

1. I can't get values of tensor from result. It returns the list of 4 values of type tensorflow.python.distribute.values.PerReplica I would need the last one.
2. I would like to get results from all iteration from the while loop.
3. I wonder if there is a more standard/elegant way how to do this.

Thanks for your suggestions!

UPDATE: I have read more on Distribute input on site https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/input
and defined input as:

```
dataset_a = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([a[i, :, :] for i in range(3000)]).batch(512)
dataset_b = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([b[i, :] for i in range(3000)]).batch(512)
dist_dataset_a = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(dataset_a)
dist_dataset_b = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(dataset_b)
```

Then I tried to use TPUStrategy like this:

```
@tf.function
def multiplication(x, y):
  return tf.linalg.matvec(x, y)
result =[]

tic = time.time()
for (x, y) in zip(dist_dataset_a, dist_dataset_b):
  result.append(strategy.run(multiplication, args=(x,y)))
toc = time.time()

print(f"First time = {toc - tic}")

result =[]

tic = time.time()
for (x, y) in zip(dist_dataset_a, dist_dataset_b):
  result.append(strategy.run(multiplication, args=(x,y)))
toc = time.time()

print(f"Second time = {toc - tic}")
```

However, the inference is much slower cca 1.2s.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I have solved it. I am posting a solution in case someone else will need it one day. The trick is that matmul can be used for batches of matrices and vectors as noted here [How does tensorflow batch_matmul work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34183343/how-does-tensorflow-batch-matmul-work). However batch_matmul does not exist any more so it is enough to call matmul.

```
@tf.function
def multiply_fn(atf, btf, experimental_relax_shapes=True):
  return tf.matmul(atf, btf)

gtf = tf.expand_dims(btf, axis=-1)
tic = time.time()
result = strategy.run(multiply_fn, args=(atf, gtf))
toc = time.time()
print(f"{toc - tic}")

tic = time.time()
result = strategy.run(multiply_fn, args=(atf, gtf))
toc = time.time()

print(f"{toc - tic}")
```

This works fast and returns results that are easy to read. Unfortunately, it repeats computation on all workers so further optimizations should be possible.
The alternative:

```
tic = time.time()
with tf.device('/TPU:0'):
  gtf = tf.linalg.matvec(atf, btf)
toc = time.time()
print(f"{toc - tic}")
```

seems to be slower for some reason cca 0.002s